# Bring Lambda environment variables to application.properties file

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

First of all I am new to Lambda function in AWS and all. I need to access the lambda environment variables into my spring-boot's application.properties file to put RDS username, pass etc. Can someone please give me any hint ?

```
  datasource:
         url: ${DBURL}
         username: ${UNAME}
         password: ${PASS}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example should work as it is in your question, are you getting any errors?

Alternatively, you could rename your environment variables to:
`SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL`, `SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME`, and `SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD` and Spring Boot will automatically pick up those values and use them, without needing anything in `application.properties`.